# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: "Inappropriate source object for this action". is identified while retrieving the connected shapes

Tags: c#, com, interop, visio

I am trying to get the connected shapes for every shape in my page. But I am finding a strange COM exception - "Inappropriate source object for this action"

Here's my code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Application visApp = new Application();
    Document visDoc = visApp.Documents.Open(filePath);

    // Get the first page in the sample drawing.
    page = visDoc.Pages[1];

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Shape shp in page.Shapes)
    {               
        GetConnected(shp, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisConnectedShapesFlags.visConnectedShapesOutgoingNodes, "", null, true);
    }
 }


    private static void GetConnected(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Shape shp, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisConnectedShapesFlags whichConnectedShapes, string category, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Selection selection, bool addToSelection)
     {
        Array aryTargetIDs;

        //getting an exception here during the second iteration of for loop of Main method
        aryTargetIDs = shp.ConnectedShapes(whichConnectedShapes, category); 
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ConnectedShapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.connectedshapes) method throws this exception for 1D shapes (ie connectors).  So you just need to include this check, either prior to calling your helper method or within it as per the following:

```c#
using Visio = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio

private static void GetConnected(
            Visio.Shape shp, 
            Visio.VisConnectedShapesFlags whichConnectedShapes, 
            string category, 
            Visio.Selection selection, 
            bool addToSelection)
{
    if (shp is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
    if (shp.OneD == 0)
    {   
        Array aryTargetIDs = shp.ConnectedShapes(whichConnectedShapes, category);
        Console.WriteLine($"{shp.Master.Name} ({shp.NameID}) - {String.Join(", ", aryTargetIDs.Cast<object>().ToArray())}");
    }
}
```

So given a set of shapes like this:
[image]

The console output from the above code would look something like this:

```
Start/End (Sheet.1) - 2
Decision (Sheet.2) - 4, 6
Subprocess (Sheet.4) - 
Document (Sheet.6) -
```